# Material-ui is so big for desktop. How to change it? Just like on mobile

Tags: responsive-design, material-ui

When I open it which is build by material-ui on pc browser it is very big, and when I open it by mobile browser it shows adaptive styling. So how to make material-ui responsive on PC?

Comment: What material UI are you talking about? Is it some certain website? A group of websites? What is "it" in your question? Asking "how to make some site responsive" is way too broad..

Comment: The style is very big on pc using material-ui, and that just the question-_-

Comment: You have to give us a link to an example at least. There are many Material UI implementations out there. You provide to few details for anyone to answer.

Comment: It has been solved, the reason should be the browser magnified.....